# Медленное появление картинки

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть вот такой код http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/10/

Как реализовать, чтобы картинка не резко появлялась, а медленно, постепенно?

Comment: Взять, да реализовать руками. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне нравится использовать вот такой [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/14/) с Jquery animate.

Comment: Отличный вариант, только проблема в том, что у меня у класса Layout позиционирование идёт, и в таком случае данный вариант не работает. Этот класс менять нельзя к тому же((    
http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/16/ - вот обновлеённый код.  
Не подскажите, как адаптировать ваш код в данном случае?

Comment: Если объясните, что именно вам нужно сделать в позиционировании элементов, то поправим, а по вашей ссылке неправильно работает отображение блока с картинкой, после получения position:absolute нужно задать этому блоку высоту и ширину, тогда всё будет отображаться: http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/17/

Answer (score 0):

Fade?
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Comment: Попробовал сделать по вашему примеру, вот код:  
http://jsfiddle.net/y07ykgzr/15/

Но ничего не происходит( Что я сделал не так?

Comment: HTML верстку сделал не так. Ты пытаешься плавно отобразить родительский для уже показанной ссылки элемент.
Вот примерно так надо http://jsfiddle.net/wf2srkfp/